# Does our Azure SQL database require more resources?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I'm working on optimizing an EF Core search method. The method times out in production when trying to return 10 records from around 20 million total. I do not have access to the logs or the production database at the moment but it is an Azure SQL database.

Our EF Core method follows all best practices for optimization as indicated here https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/entity-framework-performance-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/. The method uses `Skip()` and `Take()` and returns 10 records per call (we send the page number and number of rows in order to enable pagination).

EF Core emits the following SQL

```
  SELECT 
  [s].[ID], 
  ...
  [s.CompCancel].[ID], 
  ...
  [s.Comp].[ID], 
  ...
  [s.IncCancel].[ID], 
  ...
  [s.Inc].[ID], 
  ...
  [s.Inc.Cla].[ID], 
  ...
  [s.PolCancel].[ID], 
  ...
  [s.PolCancel.PolType].[ID], 
  ...
  [s.Pol].[ID], 
  ...
  [s.Pol.PolType].[ID], 
  ...
  [s.SupDetailsType].[ID], 
  ...
  [s.SupDetailStatus].[ID], 
  ...
FROM 
  [ufg].[SupDetails] AS [s] 
  LEFT JOIN [ufg].[CompCancel] AS [s.CompCancel] ON [s].[CompCancelID] = [s.CompCancel].[ID] 
  LEFT JOIN [ufg].[Comp] AS [s.Comp] ON [s].[CompID] = [s.Comp].[ID] 
  LEFT JOIN [ufg].[IncCancel] AS [s.IncCancel] ON [s].[IncCancelID] = [s.IncCancel].[ID] 
  LEFT JOIN [ufg].[PolType] AS [s.IncCancel.PolType] ON [s.IncCancel].[PolTypeID] = [s.IncCancel.PolType].[ID] 
  LEFT JOIN [ufg].[Inc] AS [s.Inc] ON [s].[IncID] = [s.Inc].[ID] 
  LEFT JOIN [ufg].[Cla] AS [s.Inc.Cla] ON [s.Inc].[ID] = [s.Inc.Cla].[IncID] 
  LEFT JOIN [ufg].[PolCancel] AS [s.PolCancel] ON [s].[PolCancelID] = [s.PolCancel].[ID] 
  LEFT JOIN [ufg].[PolType] AS [s.PolCancel.PolType] ON [s.PolCancel].[PolTypeID] = [s.PolCancel.PolType].[ID] 
  LEFT JOIN [ufg].[Pol] AS [s.Pol] ON [s].[PolID] = [s.Pol].[ID] 
  LEFT JOIN [ufg].[PolType] AS [s.Pol.PolType] ON [s.Pol].[PolTypeID] = [s.Pol.PolType].[ID] 
  INNER JOIN [ufg].[SupDetailsType] AS [s.SupDetailsType] ON [s].[SupDetailsTypeID] = [s.SupDetailsType].[ID] 
  INNER JOIN [ufg].[SupDetailStatus] AS [s.SupDetailStatus] ON [s].[SupDetailStatusID] = [s.SupDetailStatus].[ID] 
WHERE 
  [s].[InsertDate] >= '2022-06-08T00:00:00.0000000+02:00' 
ORDER BY 
  [s.Pol].[ID], 
  [s.Inc.Cla].[ID]
```

Without the `WHERE` clause this SQL would return ~20 million records.

I'm unfamiliar with Azure SQL DB so I need to ask, does this behavior suggest that the DB requires more resources? If so, what would those resources be (e.g. CPU, RAM)?

What metrics on Azure would indicate that more resources are needed?

Comment: Questions about performance need to include details of the tables and indexes/constraints etc, the unabridged query and the actual execution plan using *past the plan*.

Comment: Ask the person/team that designed the schema and that support the production server for assistance.

Comment: Show LINQ query. Maybe there is cartesian explosion of retrieved records.

Answer (score 1):

Your select has an "Order By"

That means that to return the "first" 10 rows it must sort the 20 million rows to know which are the first.

Also you are sorting on fields on different tables.

You could add an index with [s].[PolID] and [s].[IncID] and use those in the Order By clause